# Node.js : How to pause/resume a for loop

Tags: node.js, maxmind

I am running a for loop to generate all possible IPv4 addresses and then looking them up in maxmind's mmdb file. The problem is, while the for loop is too fast, maxmind lookup is relatively very slow and hence the processs slows down and eventually my system freezes after some 400k iterations. If I were reading from some stream, I would have paused the stream after reading every 10k ip addresses and would have resumed only when all of them have been looked up from mmdb file. But how can I have such control for a for loop ?

```
connectToMaxMindDatabases().then(function (done){
    for(var i=0; i<256; i++){
        for(var j=0; j<256; j++){
            for(var k=0; k<256; k++){
                for(var l=0; l<256; l++){
                    count++;
                    if(count % 1000 == 0){
                        console.log("count", count);
                    }
                    var newIP = getIPV4([i,j,k,l])
                    ispDB.getGeoDataAsync(newIP).then(function (result){
                        if(result){
                            console.log(count, newIP, result);
                            // process.exit();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }       
})


function getIPV4(bytes){
    return bytes.join(".")
}
```

Comment: Note that Node.js has a non-blocking philosohpy, so I think stopping the loop is maybe not a good choice. Maybe some kind of queuing?

Comment: Are you aware of the flaw in your code example that because `getGeoDataAsync` is asynchronous, by the time its result comes back `count` will have been incremented by an unpredictable amount? Not sure if it's relevant to your logic, but it's definitely something you overlooked.

Comment: @marekful I understand your point. However that does not cause any issue since I need to process all the ip addresses. If instead of for loop, it were a file, this would have not caused any issue since I would have paused the stream after reading say every 1k records and resumed only when that number of records were processed by maxmind. I would have kept a separate counter for that. But I agree with Adam, pausing the for loop will be disastrous. I am thinking of writing all the permutations to a file first.

Comment: Yes, I understand the problem. Its root is definitely in resource management of the underlying OS/Node server. A for loop with such iteration number will freeze on that particular hardware while it probably would only freeze later or none at all on a much stronger computer. The solution is to collect all IP addresses in an array first, then process them in a way that only a segment is processed at once, wait until that is finished and move to the next segment.

Comment: You should use [`mmdb-reader`](https://github.com/gosquared/mmdb-reader), which has a synchronous interface that's pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but process.nextTick might help
https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback_arg

I'm really not sure, but the following code might be used:

```
connectToMaxMindDatabases().then(function (done){
    for(var i=0; i<256; i++){
        process.nextTick(function(){
            for(var j=0; j<256; j++){
                process.nextTick(function(){
                    for(var k=0; k<256; k++){
                        process.nextTick(function(){
                            for(var l=0; l<256; l++){
                                process.nextTick(function(){
                                    count++;
                                    if(count % 1000 == 0){
                                        console.log("count", count);
                                    }
                                    var newIP = getIPV4([i,j,k,l])
                                    ispDB.getGeoDataAsync(newIP).then(function (result){
                                        if(result){
                                            console.log(count, newIP, result);
                                            // process.exit();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }       
})
```

According to my knowledge,here's what happening:
all the for loops are running synchronously, and the async ispDB.getGeoDataAsync(newIP) call is getting queued, but its callback(.then function) is not able to execute because the event loop was blocked by the 4 for loops.

Comment: thanks @manish. However, now that I am thinking again, I will be using this list frequently so it might not be a terrible idea to store it in a file and then read from there

Comment: @mandeep_m91 it sounds like you're reimplementing your own IP lookup system? Also, I seem to remember that the Maxmind EULA forbids these types of derivative works, so make sure that what you're doing is legal :-)

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is definitely in resource management of the underlying OS/Node server. A for loop with such iteration number will freeze on that particular hardware while it probably would only freeze later or none at all on a much stronger computer. The solution is to collect all IP addresses in an array first, then process them in a way that only a segment is processed at once, wait until that is finished and move to the next segment.

A possible solution can be achieved with this kind of segmentation and Bluebird's [Promse.each](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html).

> If the iterator function returns a promise or a thenable, then the
> result of the promise is awaited, before continuing with next
> iteration.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird'),
    _ = require('lodash'),
    allIPs = [];

connectToMaxMindDatabases().then(function (done){
    for(var i=0; i<256; i++){
        for(var j=0; j<256; j++){
            for(var k=0; k<256; k++){
                for(var l=0; l<256; l++){
                    count++;
                    if(count % 1000 == 0){
                        console.log("count", count);
                    }
                    var newIP = getIPV4([i,j,k,l])
                    allIPs.push(newIP);
                }
            }
        }
    }       
    return allIPs;
})
.then(function(allIPs) {
    // Create an array of arrays of IPs, each inner array with 1000 IPs
    var from = 0, to = 1000, segments = [], promises;

    do {
        segments.push(allIPs.slice(from, to));
        from += 1000; to += 1000;
    } while(to < allIPs.lenght);

    // Process a segment of 1000 IPs and wait before moving the next
    // segment until this segment is fully resolved.
    Promise.each(segments, function(segmentArr) {
        promises = [];
        _.forOwn(segmentArr, function(IP) {
            promises.push(ispDB.getGeoDataAsync(IP)
              .then(function(result) {
                  // save the result
              })
            );
        });
        return Proimse.all(promises);
    });
});
```

Of course if the resources in your case are limited in a way the `allIPs` array cannot even be produced because it starts freezing before that, this will not solve the problem, but chances are the resources are eaten up by all those `getGeoDataAsync` calls in which case this should help.

Comment: "collect all IP addresses in an array first" sounds like a memory hungry idea

Comment: That is true. So then the extraction of IP addresses should also be moved into the segmentation phase so not all of them are attempted to be collected into segments at once.